# Probability of getting k different colored balls from an urn with K different colors of balls, each color has the same number of balls

Tags: probability, distributions, sampling, multivariate-distribution, hypergeometric-distribution

Let's say I have an urn with $n$ balls, with $K$ different colors of balls, where each color has the same number of balls: $\frac{n}{K}$. Given I reach into the urn and grab a ball (without replacement) $m$ times, what is the probability of getting $k$ different colors of balls?

I asked the same question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4481749/probability-of-getting-k-different-colored-balls-from-an-urn-with-k-different-co), and has one person commenting on it. I am wondering if anyone on this forum has additional useful insight.

Comment: You really need to show what you have tried.  For example, what is the probability the first ball drawn is a new colour? (hint: $1$)  If it is, then what is the probability the second draw is a new colour and what is the probability the two draws are different.  And so on.

Comment: You want multivariate hypergeometric distribution https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution#Multivariate_hypergeometric_distribution

Comment: @Tim: do you want to turn that into an answer?